# Run didFinshLaunchingWithOptions in the AppDelegate while application is running?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, appdelegate

Is there a way i can execute the

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method while the app is running from a different ViewController?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have set some designs in the app delegate.   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions    but i have given the option to change these within the app.  Would i need to change within each ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a separate method in your app delegate for setting nav bar appearance.

In your AppDelegate.h file, declare the same method.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

-(void)setNavBarAppearance;

@end
```

In the appDelegate.m file, write the functionality for that method

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self setNavBarAppearance];
}


-(void)setNavBarAppearance {
    //Do what is required here.
}

@end
```

Then, wherever you need to call the same method:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate setNavBarAppearance];
```

Comment: It works but doesn't refresh instantly, the changes only take affect when i close and re-open the application. Any ideas?

Comment: Just call the code for setting the nav bar directly wherever needed, no need for the app delegate at all

Comment: Got it have to refresh it using self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor;

Answer (score 0):

You should not call the delegate methods by your own, You can use `NSNotificationCenter`

1. Write the code you want to execute in a different method (`someThingInterestingHappened`) in our case.
2. Register the class to notification by calling `addObserver` on `defaultNotificationCenter` , i.e. `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someThingInterestingHappened:) name:@"desiredEventHappend" object:nil];`
3. Post the notification from any class `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"desiredEventHappend" object:nil];`

Comment: step 2. is what i use in the app delegate?

Comment: yes, you can add observer in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions `